# Shared Forms Authentication not working between .NET 3.5 and .NET 4.0 applications

Tags: asp.net, authentication, forms-authentication, asp.net-3.5, asp.net-4.0

I have two web applications, one running under .Net 3.5, the other has been upgraded to .Net 4.0. Prior to the upgrade, shared authentication was setup and working correctly between the two applications as indicated in the MSDN article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eb0zx8fc.aspx

The 3.5 Application is running under the Classic .NET AppPool (v2.0, Classic Pipeline).

The 4.0 application is running under the ASP .NET v4.0 AppPool (v4.0, Integrated Pipeline).

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be the App Pool the .NET 3.5 application was running under. We switched the app pool to ASP .NET v4.0 Classic (without upgrading the application itself to run under 4.0 / vs2010).

Shared authentication is back to normal. I could not find this listed as a requirement anywhere so hopefully this will save someone else some time in the future.

Comment: This article - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eb0zx8fc(v=vs.100).aspx - Points out the particular requirements of sharing forms authentication tickets between 2.0 and later applications (3.5 uses the 2.0 runtime, so I believe it applies). In that case, you need to set `decryption="3DES"`